# How to retrieve Firestore data using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was now trying for days to retrieve my firestore values, but no luck so posting it here.

I have a Firestore database and some data. I want to retrieve this with the help of Flutter.

This is what I have been doing.

So I have a Flutter screen where it shows a simple 3-dot dropdown in the `AppBar`.

It has two options: `edit` and `cancel`.

What I want is, when I press edit, it should open a new screen and should pass the data that I retrieved from firestore.

This is where I have `edit` and `cancel` dropdown (3 dots) and calling the a function (to retrieve data and open the new screen).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.news.headline.toUpperCase()),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: (value) {
              _open_edit_or_delete(value); // caling the function here
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return {'Edit', 'Delete'}.map((String choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _get_particular_news(widget.news),
    );
  }
```

and this is the `open_edit_or_delete` function it is calling. But it doesn't open up (navigate) to the screen I am calling.

```
open_edit_or_delete(String selectedOption) {
    News news;
    Visibility(
        visible: false,
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FireStoreServiceApi().getNews(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<News>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstScreen(news:news)));
              return null;
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  news = snapshot.data[index];
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
```

And in case you need the `FireStoreServiceApi().getNews()`, here it is as well.

```
  // get the news
  Stream<List<News>> getNews() {
    return _db.collection("news").snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
              .toList(),
        ) ;
  }
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: can you add what is happening now? i think you always getting redirect to FirstScreen ? am i right ?

Comment: nothing happens. Screen stays the same. It is a widget, I guess that is the issue. I have used the widget because I don't know how to retrieve the data as `News` object without `StreamBuilder` widget. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing data correctly to your fromMap method.

You can access data using doc.data['']

If you have data and documentID property in it then following will work.

```
 News.fromMap(doc.data.data, doc.data.documentID))
```

I don't know your fromMap method and i also don't what your snapshot contains, if this did not work for you then add them too.